# Spike in measured execution time of a C expression using floating point maths using FPU

Tags: performance, floating-point, real-time, timing

As we are working on floating point extensive code in C, I see sudden spikes in time taken for expressions involving `pow(double,double)` function. I do not understand why a particular number passed to `pow()` function causing sudden spurt in time of execution though the values vary continuously with a difference between each value in the order of 0.00001 or lesser. The expression is similar to **(in a Kernel module, on customized Linux for hard real time)**:

dbl_type_var0 is continuously fed in loop around 300.000 increasing with variation in the order 1.0, or 1 to 3 after decimals point, like 300.0,300.1,301.003,301.5,302.0,303.1,303.2 etc which is calculated from another function.

```
double_type_var2 = 1005.0;
dbl_type_var4 = 34.1/6.15;
double_type_var1 = double_type_var2*pow(dbl_type_var0/303.15,dbl_type_var4);
```

The floating point processor is available and enabled the fp using RTOS specific thread api to enable fp hardware for corresponding thread ie `pthread_setfp_np(pthread_handle,bool_enable_disable)`.
The execution time measured using hardware timer for above expression on the platform is around 5 times the execution time when the spike is not present.During remaining time, ie with other values lesser than 1 millisec. This specific function or line of code is causing problem of timing.

I need help in resolving this or understanding the reason behind this.
I have enabled floating point exceptions and this particular code line has not caused any exception. Do the processor/floating point hardware execution time vary so randomly for continuous varying values for same function?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you give some details on the code. 0.5ms or even 0.1ms to compute one pow() are *by far* too much.

Comment: Is the math library used here open source? If so, which library is being used (please be as specific as possible)? What processor is being used? In the slow cases, you are possibly hitting a slow path in the `pow()` implementation, or the hardware itself (e.g. handling of subnormals/denormals).

Comment: There are **many** factors that can cause this, and you have given almost no information, not even the input values to `pow` that trigger the issue. For example (just to illustrate that the range of potential causes is wide), one possible cause is that some lookup table `pow` uses to reduce operands or assist in calculation logarithms or exponentials has an entry that falls in a cache set that conflicts with something else, causing some cache thrashing that other table entries do not.

Comment: No look up table has been used. The math library is provided by vendor along with the compiler which for the ppc board. ppc_xxxx_gcc. I would provide the values passed. Editing the question to give values passed. I mentioned regarding the floating point processor as being enabled.

Comment: @njuffa I believe this is the reason, but request further inputs regarding the same. Will check the same from my side. math lib should be similar to the one provided along with gcc, but customized for the hardware. Cannot provide more details regarding the library due to access limitations.

Comment: @Alain Merigot , sorry, I do not have immediate access to the execution environment. Corrected the question. But the spike is 5 times than during with no spike and this particular execution instance is leading to decision regarding timing of entire system.

Comment: @DevBee `pow()` is often implemented with the help of (specialized) `exp()` and `log()` implementations (or alternatively, `exp2()` / `log2()` functions). In several widely-used `pow()` implementations, these underlying building blocks utilize lookup tables. I believe this is what Eric Postpischil is referring to. Unless you inspect the source code of your math library, you would not be aware of these lookup tables.

Comment: The edits reveal the first argument to `pow` spans one, which is suggestive—the magnitude of a logarithm diminishes near one, which could trigger `pow` behavior issues in various ways. Aside from that, there is still too little information. We are not given the **exact** values that trigger the undesired behavior nor code to reproduce them nor details of the library being used. We are left to hypothesize about too much. So I will vote to close due to insufficient information. ([njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/780717/njuffa) is correct about the nature of my comment on tables.)

Comment: I will note one avenue for exploration/hope would be to use alternative calculations, possibly `log1p` and `expm1` to deal with the pow-near-one issue. A [mcve] would both enable participants to explore the exact values involved (even if participants could not reproduce the timing but OP specifically identified the troublesome cases) and enable participants to examine the calculations to suggest alternatives.

Comment: @njuffa enabling -ffast-math removed the spikes. I read the option disregards IEEE representation for denormals, but not technically aware what is happening in detail. Apart from this detail, it would be great to know how do I handle while writing code itself, as a best practice to avoid these kind of unpredictable  behavior with esp with math expressions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That is really helpful, and will explore possility of using log1p and expm1. As I mentioned, for now worked around using -ffastmath, but would work on to understand and analyze. Thanks a lot. This can be concluded here.